# Atomic Sequence using Hazelcast

Tags: multithreading, hazelcast

USE CASE: Create AtomicSequence using last saved id in DB (not start from zero) and generate id after last saved id in db.
       First we are checking if AtomicSequence instance is there or not if not we create AtomicSequence from last saved id (if the entry is in db.).

In HazelcastAtomicSequenceManager getSequenceGenerator method is two-step process.

Step 1: getHzInstance().getAtomicLong(key). // It will get if not present create a new one with 0 initial value.
Step 2: this.sequence.compareAndSet(0, startVal); // set value if initial value is zero.

Now consider Thread 1 come check and see the AtomicSequence for the given key is not present and execute stpe1 still did not execute step 2.
Thread 2 come and see the AtomicSequence is created (As step 1 is executed by thread1) and go ahead and increment it to 1.As the initial value still zero as Thread 2 did not execute step 2.
Now thread 1 will try to execute step2 but unable to it as initial value became 1 or something not equal to zero. So the atomicsequence will generate id from 1 next instead it should start from last save id, Due to which our test case is failing.
Any way to fix this issue

Answer (score -1):

You need to get and try compareAndSet in a loop, until it succeeds:

```html
        long current;
        do {
            current = atomicLong.get();
        } while (!atomicLong.compareAndSet(current, startVal));
```

Comment: I think the problem is the atomic-sequence should start from last saved id.If thread with zero start value win that will initialize to 1.I think it should support public IAtomicLong getAtomicLong(String name, long initVal, boolean create)

Comment: I understand your need. Did you mean IAtomicLong getAtomicLong(String name, long initVal). Yes, it can be discussed if the API can be extended to provide an initial value. You can open an issue for this at the github repo.

Comment: I have already created one issue.Please find the link below https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/10696